CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (find_package):
ubuntu 20.04.6
ROS2 FOXY
LD19
Hello guys,
I have meta problem while using my new LdLidar.
I have followed every step of this tuto: https://github.com/ldrobotSensorTeam/ldlidar_stl_ros2?tab=readme-ov-file#Instructions. And there is a video of the tuto:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJWAsV6-0GE.
And when i tried to build it with "colcon build" i had:
Starting >>> ldlidar_stl_ros2
--- stderr: ldlidar_stl_ros2
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (find_package):
By not providing "Findament_cmake.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
"ament_cmake", but CMake did not find one.
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ament_cmake" with
any of the following names:
ament_cmakeConfig.cmake
ament_cmake-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "ament_cmake" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"ament_cmake_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"ament_cmake" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
has been installed.

Failed   <<< ldlidar_stl_ros2 [0.15s, exited with code 1]
Summary: 0 packages finished [0.40s]
1 package failed: ldlidar_stl_ros2
1 package had stderr output: ldlidar_stl_ros2
Does someone has any idea or that?

Check if the requirement package installed
sudo apt install ros-foxy-ament-cmake-clang-format

it works, i manage to build it, thanks i lot. I wanted to check it but i didn't found out how.

I'm glad it worked. Have a nice ROS life!

Be aware that Foxy is EOL, consider update to a supported version.
Have you installed ROS properly, and sourced it? (e.g., source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash)

Yes i have. And I have followed all the steps of the FOXY documentation.
